# Implement Cloudways CDN with Craft

Tags: plugins, cdn

Is there any way or plugin to implement Cloudways CDN with Craft?

Comment: There is a CDN plugin called Upper. You could do a feature request on there https://github.com/ostark/upper/issues . Or look at how they implement the CDNs in their plugins and make your own.

Answer (score 1):

There is a CDN plugin called Upper. You could do a feature request on there github.com/ostark/upper/issues . Or look at how they implement the CDNs in their plugins and make your own.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Cloudways is just a pull CDN, so you probably won't have to do anything to support it, just set up the origin properly, and change your Asset URLs as appropriate.

The TL;DR on pull CDNs is that you give them an "origin" (your website in most cases), and change your asset URLs to point to the CDN. When an asset is requested, it looks for it in its cache, and if it isn't there, it pulls it from the origin (your website) and caches it.

So there's very little setup you need to do just to get the basic functionality working.

You won't get any automatic purging, that'd have to come from a plugin or such, but it should work without modification in Craft CMS.

I've done similar things setting up MaxCDN to work with Craft CMS.